# React component return type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have basic context provider

```
export function StepsPropvider ({
  children,
  ...props
}: React.PropsWithChildren<StepsProps>) => {
  return <Steps.Provider value={props}>
    {typeof children === 'function'
     ? (children as React.FC<StepsProps>)(props)
     : children} 
  </Steps.Provider>);
};
```

Then

```
<StepsPropvider>
  {(x) => (<span>{x.someProp}</span>)} // x has any type
</StepsPropvider>
```

The problem is that my `x` inside StepProvider has any type. How can I fix it?

I want something like this
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok first of all you are doing something very weird . In your case `{(x) => (<span>{x.someProp}</span>)}` is children and has type `ReactNode`, so that's why `x` is any, you didn't provide any type for `x`. `x` is just the variable in func

Comment: I added screenshot , what i want to achiev